# Iterate through entire JSON object without knowing any keys

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, web

I'm attempting to perform operations (update values, delete keys, add keys, etc.) on JSON data which I do not know anything about.  These items are essentially property files and not JSON data returned from an application.  These files could be very different and I need to develop a method that can perform these operations without knowing anything about the JSON data.

I am keeping track of the path of where the key is stored.  If I had sample data as shown below, I would store the path like '/key1/innerKey5/' and get the data with the key innerKey6 using getNodeData.

If I had the path and the key of the item, how can I programmatically find this item in the JSON data and delete or update the item?

```
var originalData = someMethodToGetJSONData();
var currentData; // Global variable storing a copy of the original data which can be modified

json = {
  "key1": {
    "innerKey1": {
      "innerKey2" : {
        "innerKey3": "value1",
        "innerKey4": "value2"
      }
    },
    "innerKey5": {
      "innerKey6": "value1"
    }
  },
  "key2": "value3",
  "key3": "value4"
}

function getKeysFromPath(keyPath) {
  var split = keyPath.split('/');
  var keys = [];

  for(var i = 0; i < split.length; i++) {
    if(split[i] != '') {
      keys.push(split[i]);
    }
  }

  return keys
}

function getNodeData(keyPath) {
  var keys = getKeysFromPath(keyPath);
  nodeData = currentItemData;

  for(var i = 0; i < keys.length; i++) {
    nodeData = nodeData[keys[i]];
  }

  return nodeData;
}

data = getNodeData('/key1/innerKey5/');
key = 'innerKey6';
console.log('Data: ' + data[key]);
```

Comment: Pet peeve: JSON object has only two properties: `parse` and `stringify`. You have a *JavaScript object*, or just an *object*, not a JSON object.

Comment: look into using [Object.keys()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/keys)

Comment: @Amadan You're right, thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Lodash has some useful function for doing this sort of thing.

_.get, _.set, _.unset

So if you store the node as string form  eg. -> a.b.c[0].k, these 3 functions should be able to do what you want.

Comment: This looks to be the quickest and easiest option.  Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

This is an example of how to iterate through unknown keys

```
var key;

for (key in arr) {
  if (arr.hasOwnProperty(key)) {
    console.log(key);
    console.log(arr[key]);
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are using JQuery, use the .each() function:

```
$.each(json,function(key,val){
        //You may use key/val for every iteration
});
```

Answer (score 0):

In order to update or delete, you need to get the parent object and the last key:

```
var lastKey = keys.pop();
var parentObj = getNodeByKeys(keys); // refactor your code to make this function
parentObj[lastKey] = newValue;
delete parentObj[lastKey];
```

Answer (score 0):

Get the data via XHR and parse JSON:

```
var getJSON = function(url) {
    return new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
        var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
        xhr.open('get', url, true);
        xhr.onload = function() {
            var status = xhr.status;
            if (status == 200) {
                resolve(JSON.parse(xhr.response));
            } else {
                reject(status);
            }
        };
        xhr.send();
    });
};
```

then use jQuery `each`:

```
getJSON('//yoursite.com/yourfile.json').then(function(data) {
    $.each(data, function(k, v) {
      console.log(k + ', ' + v);
    });
}, function(status) {
    console.log(status);
});
```

Comment: if you are going to throw jQuery in just to use `each` why not use `$.getJSON` also?

Comment: True.  I find native JS XHR is easy cross-broswer (wES6 shim) but found iterating objects nontrivial in native JS.  So `$.each` is easy cross browser.  My preference is native JS, that's all.

Comment: In native JS you could do: `Object.keys(json).forEach(function(key){  });`. Almost the same thing as jQuery.

Answer (score 0):

You can get data from a "path" using this function:

```
/**
 * Get a node from an object according to the given path.
 * @param {String} path Node's path.
 * @param {Object} data Object to retrieve the desired information.
 * @returns {Object} Returns the value from the node, or null in the
 * case the node is not found.
 */
function getNode(path, data)
{
    var currentNode = data;

    path.replace(/^\/|\/$/g, '').split('/').forEach(function(key){
        if(key in currentNode)
        {
            currentNode = currentNode[key];
        }
        else
        {
            currentNode = null;
            return false;
        }
    });

    return currentNode;
}
```

From there you could manipulate your object like this:

```
var myData = {
    "key1": {
        "innerKey1": {
            "innerKey2" : {
                "innerKey3": "value1",
                "innerKey4": "value2"
            }
        },
        "innerKey5": {
            "innerKey6": "value1"
        }
    },
    "key2": "value3",
    "key3": "value4"
};

var someNode = getNode('/key1/innerKey5', myData);

// add value
someNode.innerKey7 = 'newValue';

// update existing value
someNode.innerKey7 = 'otherValue';

// delete value
delete someNode.innerKey6;

console.log(myData);
```